# Windows phone 7-Need Background job which runs for every 30 second when my app is running

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need some kind of background job which automatically checks for the network availability and syncs the data which is present in the isolated storage and this job should run in parallel when my app is running and it should run for every 30seconds.
please provide some suggestion. I tried of periodic task but it will run only once for every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some code to execute periodically while your app is running then you can use `DispatchTimer` with a 30 sec interval.

But why would you want to periodically check for network connectivity? You should just execute any code that requires connectivity and handle any network related errors with a try/catch block.

Comment: My requirement is i want to sync data automatically present in my isolated storage. My app stores data in isolated storage if there is no network availability...and i want to sync that data as soon as i get network how can i do that

Comment: Well DispatchTimer should work fine for your use case.